# React - Setting component state using a function outside of state, is it wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Is it wrong to use setState in a function outside of the React component?

Example:

```js
// myFunction.js
function myFunction() {
  ...
  this.setState({ ... })
}

// App.js
import myFunction from './myFunction

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.myFunction = myFunction.bind(this)
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: It is not wrong. You're essentially creating a mixin function.

Comment: @corasan does code in this way actually run for you?

Comment: @Colin yeah it does, works perfectly

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the way you're binding will actually work. You could do something like:

```
export const getName = (klass) => {
  klass.setState({ name: 'Colin'})
}
```

then

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'React'
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    getName(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>change name</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b666y6?file=index.js).

Comment: Yeah it works how I have it in the example, I'm just wondering if it's anti pattern and shouldn't do that, like negative effects on the component, etc.

Comment: upvoted, because of the new approach, but I have the same question as the op. Should this way of writing be encouraged?  I guess not.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use it, and I've also never seen it used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

So the only reasons to do this is if you are reducing repeated code, e.g. two components use the same logic before calling `this.setState`, or if you want to make testing easier by having a separate pure function to test. For this reason I recommend **not** calling `this.setState` in your outside function, but rather returning the object you need so it can you can call `this.setState` on it.

```
function calculateSomeState(data) {
  // ...
  return { updated: data };
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = calculateSomeState(props.data);
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState(calculateSomeState({ ...props.data, value }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug waiting to happen... If you want to use an external function to set state, you can use the alternative syntax provided by React:

```
this.setState((prevState, props)  => {
  return updatedState; //can be a partial state, like in the regular setState
});
```

That callback can easily be extracted to an external function and it's guaranteed to work

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong, the function is never called outside the component. This is a mix-in technique. `bind` isn't needed, as long as the function isn't used as a callback. In this case `myFunction` is same among all instances, a more efficient way would be:

```
class App extends Component {}
App.prototype.myFunction = myFunction;
```

Comment: "bind isn't needed, as long as the function isn't used as a callback." – can you explain this?

Comment: It should be bound if it's passed as a callback, e.g. `onClick={this.myFunction}`. It shouldn't be bound if it's called with proper context like `this.myFunction()`. Where do you use this function?